# Reading an excel with pandas basing on columns' colors

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an xlsx file, with columns with various coloring.

I want to read only the white columns of this excel in python using pandas, but I have no clues on hot to do this.

I am able to read the full excel into a dataframe, but then I miss the information about the coloring of the columns and I don't know which columns to remove and which not.

Comment: Please post what you have so far to _"read the full excel"_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**(Disclosure: I'm one of the authors of the library I'm going to suggest)**

With [StyleFrame](https://github.com/DeepSpace2/StyleFrame) (that wraps pandas) you can read an excel file into a dataframe without loosing the style data.

Consider the following sheet:

[image]

And the following code:

```
from styleframe import StyleFrame, utils
# from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, utils (if using version < 3.X)

sf = StyleFrame.read_excel('test.xlsx', read_style=True)
print(sf)

#          b  p                  y
#     0  nan  3             1000.0
#     1  3.0  4                2.0
#     2  4.0  5  42902.72396767148

sf = sf[[col for col in sf.columns
         if col.style.fill.fgColor.rgb in ('FFFFFFFF', utils.colors.white)]]
         # "white" can be represented as 'FFFFFFFF' or
         # '00FFFFFF' (which is what utils.colors.white is set to)
print(sf)

#          b
#    0   nan
#    1   3.0
#    2   4.0
```

Comment: The included example appears to be based on an old version of the API.

Comment: @Isaac Why? what errors did you run into when trying to use it?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'fill'

Comment: But col.style.bg_color in (colours) seems to work

Comment: Which I found by following your link above -- but couldn't find fill.fgColor -- hence my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done in pandas. You will need to use other library to read the xlsx file and determine what columns are white. I'd suggest using `openpyxl` library.

Then your script will follow this steps:

1. Open xlsx file
2. Read and filter the data (you can access the cell color) and save the results
3. Create pandas dataframe

Edit: Switched `xlrd` to `openpyxl` as `xlrd` is no longer actively maintained

Comment: You cannot read xlsx file using xlrd library. Only xls can be read using xlrd.