# How to get the cell's format (font and font color) using gspread and pandas

Tags: pandas, gspread

I used the following code to get the value of a cell in my google sheet:

```
client = gspread.service_account_from_dict(creds)
hrfile = client.open('HR Data')
hrsheet = hrfile.get_worksheet(0)
H1 = hrsheet.acell('B3').value
```

How can I get the font and font color of that cell? There is no option like `hrsheet.acell('B3').font`, `hrsheet.acell('B3').format` or `hrsheet.acell('B3').color`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading an excel with pandas basing on columns' colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861989/reading-an-excel-with-pandas-basing-on-columns-colors)

Comment: @eshirvana - Google Sheets is not Microsoft Excel.

Comment: Before I noticed this question, I have posted an answer to [your this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73738358). I apologize for this. Could you please confirm it?